# Android: headphone buttons with USB-C adapter

Tags: android, linux, button, headphones, adaptor

I want to make my headphone buttons work through an USB-C adapter because my phone is so hip and modern that it doesn't have a 3.5mm jack.

The buttons work: using the app "KeyEvent Display", I figured out that

- `Vol+` triggers "linux key code number" 114
- `Vol-`  triggers "linux key code number" 259
- `Play/Pause`  triggers "linux key code number" 226

By changing `/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl` to

```
key 114 VOLUME_UP
key 226 HEADSETHOOK
key 259 VOLUME_DOWN
```

I got the expected behaviour of the headset buttons, but it interfered with the regular buttons on the phone.
That's why I want to create a **device-specific config file**. For this, I need either the device name or the vendor and product IDs. (As explained in the [android documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files).)

How can I do this?

PS: The app "USB Device Info" didn't show any connected devices. [Here](https://pastebin.com/902uEcUn) you can find the output of `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`. Relevant output of the app "Under the Hood": `pastebin.com/kDeBNS0H`

PPS: Solving this problem will give you extra karma, because the solution will be fed into LineageOS, solving the problem for many people!

Comment: I tried the following file names (rebooting every time): `Vendor_0000_Product_0003.kl`, `Vendor_0000_Product_0000.kl`, `Vendor_0001_Product_0001.kl`, but none worked.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww: you're right. i've found an answer, though, and i'm posting it just for the record.

Comment: How does one downvote a comment? :)

Comment: which comment? jww's is legitimate. (why) did you downvote my question and my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [keytest](https://github.com/chrisboyle/keytest) app, I found out that the device ID of the headphones     (2) differed from the device ID of the regular volume buttons (7 and 3).
Now, I only had to find out the device name corresponding to the device ID. This I did using a terminal emulator:

```
$ su
$ getevent
add device 1: /dev/input/event7
name: "msm8976-skun-snd-card Headset Jack"
add device 2: /dev/input/event6
name: "msm8976-skun-snd-card Button Jack"
add device 3: /dev/input/event4
name: "qpnp_pon"
add device 4: /dev/input/event3
name: "qwerty"
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse1, Not a typewriter
add device 5: /dev/input/event2
name: "hbtp_vm"
add device 6: /dev/input/event1
name: "input_mt_wrapper"
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
add device 7: /dev/input/event5
name: "gpio-keys"
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
add device 8: /dev/input/event0
name: "synaptics_dsx_s2"
```

According to the [documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files), all characters other than `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z` and `-` are replaced by `_`. Thus, I created a new file: `/system/usr/keylayout/msm8976-skun-snd-card_Button_Jack.kl` with the following content:

```
# Configuration file for LeEco Le 2 headphone buttons
key 114 VOLUME_UP
key 226 HEADSETHOOK
key 259 VOLUME_DOWN
```

After a reboot, I got the expected behaviour!